Sort kubernetes NetworkPolicy by ports and then by ipBlock using yq
I have the following kubernetes NetworkPolicy file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    acm_host_group: 10.20.30.40/27,11.20.30.40/27
    acm_manifest_date: "2024-06-14T10:55:53.118658117Z"
    acm_user: SOME_USER
    platform: aws
  name: net-policy-name
  namespace: net-policy-namespace
spec:
  egress:
    - ports:
        - port: "6668"
          protocol: TCP
        - port: "7082"
          protocol: TCP
      to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.125.168.151/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.75.125.250/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 20.168.200.109/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.69.6.27/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.102.220.40/32
    - ports:
        - port: "443"
          protocol: TCP
      to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.32.117/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.24.104/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.0.95/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.0.121/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.96.129.17/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.96.129.18/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.24.127/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.96.129.19/32
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - ingress
    - egress

I would like to order the entries so that the ports are sorted by spec.egress[].ports[].port and then by spec.egress[].ports[].protocol and then the ipBlocks are sorted by cidr.  So above would look like this:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    acm_host_group: 10.20.30.40/27,11.20.30.40/27
    acm_manifest_date: "2024-06-14T10:55:53.118658117Z"
    acm_user: SOME_USER
    platform: aws
  name: net-policy-name
  namespace: net-policy-namespace
spec:
  egress:
    - ports:
        - port: "443"
          protocol: TCP
      to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.96.129.17/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.96.129.18/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.96.129.19/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.0.95/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.0.121/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.24.104/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.24.127/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 76.88.32.117/32
    - ports:
        - port: "6668"
          protocol: TCP
        - port: "7082"
          protocol: TCP
      to:
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 20.168.200.109/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.69.6.27/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.75.125.250/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.102.220.40/32
        - ipBlock:
            cidr: 22.125.168.151/32
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
    - ingress
    - egress

I ultimately want to be able to compare/diff two files that have their elements in different orders.  I've looked at this for a while and can't seem to come up with a decent solution.  One option I considered was to convert to properties files (as per https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/tips-and-tricks#comparing-yaml-files) and then use sed/awk/grep to make my tweaks but that's a bit ugly.  If anyone is up for a challenge I'd appreciate some guidance.


NOTE A better approach may be to expand the ports and ipBlock's so that you have port*ipBlock for every port and cidr. Otherwise, I worry that presenting the YAML as canonical won't necessary show equivalence.

I'm unsure whether yq is able to do this; one challenge I have is iterating over the .spec.egress.to arrays and sorting them.
This should be relatively straightforward in e.g. Python. The following was eye-balled on your example.
Caveat developer:
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install pyyaml

canonical.py:
import sys
import yaml

# Parse stdin as YAML
y = yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin)

# Iterate over .spec.egress
for egress in y["spec"]["egress"]:
    # Sort .ports by port
    egress["ports"].sort(key=lambda x: x["port"])
    # Sort .to by ipBlock.cidr
    egress["to"].sort(key=lambda x: x["ipBlock"]["cidr"])

# Sort the result by the first ports port
y["spec"]["egress"].sort(key=lambda x: x["ports"][0]["port"])

# Write the resutlt to stdout
yaml.dump(y, sys.stdout)

And:
cat example.yaml > python3 canonical.py

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  annotations:
    acm_host_group: 10.20.30.40/27,11.20.30.40/27
    acm_manifest_date: '2024-06-14T10:55:53.118658117Z'
    acm_user: SOME_USER
    platform: aws
  name: net-policy-name
  namespace: net-policy-namespace
spec:
  egress:
  - ports:
    - port: '443'
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.96.129.17/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.96.129.18/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.96.129.19/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 76.88.0.121/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 76.88.0.95/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 76.88.24.104/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 76.88.24.127/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 76.88.32.117/32
  - ports:
    - port: '6668'
      protocol: TCP
    - port: '7082'
      protocol: TCP
    to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 20.168.200.109/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.102.220.40/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.125.168.151/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.69.6.27/32
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 22.75.125.250/32
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - ingress
  - egress


This worked great.  One of the files I have is manually created, the other system-generated.   As such if the spec.egress.ports.port file is missing a quote around the field the sort fails with an odd error.  Also the manually created file can also have comments within it.  I''m using yq to clean the one file before calling: ```yq -P "... comments="" | .spec.egress.[].ports[].port |= to_string" file1.yaml > file1-NO-COMMENTS.yaml
cat file1-NO-COMMENTS.yaml > python3 canonical.py > file1-SORTED.yaml
cat file2.yaml > python3 canonical.py > file2-SORTED.yaml
now diff the 2 files```

Yes, unfortunately, there's almost no error-checking. The port field should never omit the quotes because, while YAML would permit it, the validation assumes the value is an integer rather than a string.
